# Restrict URL access control by id in jhipster

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, jhipster

I have a problem that each user can retrieve other users data from URL.

For instance, I have a rest api like this:

```
@GetMapping("/getFindByPersonId/{perId}")
@Timed
public List<ComboVahedAmoozeshi> getFindBySkhsIdCombo(@PathVariable Long perId){
    return comboVahedAmoozeshiRepository.getFindBySkhsIdCombo(perId);
}
```

After authorization, each user can change id and get other users data like the image below:

[image]

Is there any suggestion to restrict each user to don`t have access to call the method? Or Jhipster have any options to use UUId to hide id?

Comment: Are these your custom generated entities? If yes you need to implement object level restrictions on your own. Maybe method security is enough (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#method-security-expressions) or you have to implement access control list to restrict access to an entity (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#domain-acls). As jhipster does not know about your domain it just generates basic access control via user and admin role to prevent unauthorized access to an api.

Comment: @atomfrede Do you mean jhipster considered for generated CRUD? This sample is customed but there is no difference between customed or jhipstere generated. For instance, on every edit page, you can change the id in the URL and fetch other data.

Comment: Thats correct. What I try to say is, thats by design. You can access every entity as an authenticated user. JHipster does not know if some entity must be restricted to a certain user. You have to implement further measures (e.g. via an ACL or some kind of post filter) to do that.

Comment: But, how can I restrict for a record? user A with role_user can access to entityA. records in entityA with user_id blongs to user A. user B with role_user also have access to entity A. But, user B also have access to user A records(by URL and API)

Comment: either you can use acls or which might already suite your usecase is to use PostAuthorize filter. With that filter you can define an expression (like the userId of the current user must match the property X of the returned object) which prevents returning an object from a method if the user is not allowed to read it. See for example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security. You have to enable global method security for jhipster as it is not enabled by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks from @atomferede for the right answer. I have to add jhi_user_id in other entities and used @postfilter annotation to limit user's access to data.
Although, maybe it`s a good idea to have this option in jhipster generator to enhance the security level and faster implementation.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this is useful and can be integrated into the codegenerator you can start with a module/blueprint.