# JHipster: How to restrict user to access own data with REST

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth, authorization, jhipster

JHipster implements several best practices for authentication and authorization.
Mainly described here: https://www.jhipster.tech/security/.
But I still do not see an example how to design a solution, which does not involve putting user verification logic all over the place for a very common use case.

Let's say you have a WebPage using REST-API like [BankAccountResource from JHipster Sample App](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/fc3864a13371b77c9a6dc5602dba9bc5b4cd6f7e/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/BankAccountResource.java#L141) and you want to restrict this to only ADMIN role or currently logged in User. Let's say you have 50 of such services for your customers: BankAccount, Address, BillingAddress, UserData, Devices... For every resource a GET and UPDATE must be restricted. Also loading device /api/device/{id} might not include user-id.

1. How do I prevent UserA from loading UserB's device by guessing it's id?
2. How do I avoid planting that code in every method?
3. I guess JHipster/SpringSecurity has concept/objects to handle such use cases. Could you point me, explain how to use them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this question helps a little bit: [Restrict URL access control by id in jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107075/restrict-url-access-control-by-id-in-jhipster)

Spring Security hast `PostFilter`s to check if an object e.g. loaded by a method may be accessed. If you need more control you can use Access Control Lists for fine grained access control.

References:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#domain-acls
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#method-security-expressions

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.